# translate this block of C physics code to python

Tags: python, c

I have only learnt python for for few months and totally a newb in C, I got a C code from the web, and I am dying to study it. But i only understand python language, so would someone can help to translate the following code to python would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) { /* Foreach particle "i" ... */
  ax=0.0;
  ay=0.0;
  az=0.0;
  for(j=0; j<n; j++) { /* Loop over all particles "j" */
    dx=x[j]-x[i];
    dy=y[j]-y[i];
    dz=yz[j]-z[i];
    invr = 1.0/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps);
    invr3 = invr*invr*invr;
    f=m[j]*invr3;
    ax += f*dx; /* accumulate the acceleration from gravitational attraction */
    ay += f*dy;
    az += f*dx;
  }
  xnew[i] = x[i] + dt*vx[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*ax; /* update position of particle "i" */
  ynew[i] = y[i] + dt*vy[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*ay;
  znew[i] = z[i] + dt*vz[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*az;
  vx[i] += dt*ax; /* update velocity of particle "i" */
  vy[i] += dt*ay;
  vz[i] += dt*az;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: The code, with the comments is really easy to understand.  What are you having trouble with?  The code results in division by zero in the calculation of `inver` when `i == j` though.

Comment: This is n-body agravity code, right? Taken from http://www.browndeertechnology.com/docs/BDT_OpenCL_Tutorial_NBody.html ? Explain to me why there is a computation when i == j. That means that not only do the n-1 other objects influence the current body but it influences itself, too. Read the wikipedia page this is based on(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem). It expressly omits that combination from the calculation, right? I'm not a physics guy but that's how I read the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a literal translation

(**Edit**: *was* a literal translation but there are some anomalies in the original C code which @hughdbrown pointed out in comments -- looks like you're trying to study this subject from code so utterly broken it wouldn't even compile, which seems very unwise on your part, so, anyway, I'm taking the liberty of fixing the apparent errors and absurdities of the original C code in this Python "almost"-literal translation...):

```
import math

for i in range(n):
  ax = ay = az = 0.0
  for j in range(n):
    dx=x[j]-x[i]
    dy=y[j]-y[i]
    dz=z[j]-z[i]
    invr = 1.0/math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps)
    f=m[j]*invr**3
    ax += f*dx  # accumulate the acceleration from gravitational attraction
    ay += f*dy
    az += f*dz
  xnew[i] = x[i] + dt*vx[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*ax
  ynew[i] = y[i] + dt*vy[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*ay
  znew[i] = z[i] + dt*vz[i] + 0.5*dt*dt*az
  vx[i] += dt*ax  # update velocity of particle "i"
  vy[i] += dt*ay
  vz[i] += dt*az
```

Of course it assumes lists x, y, z, ... vx, vy, vz are all pre-existing and of the same length `n`, just like the C code snippet assumes for the same-named arrays.

Comment: A literal translation -- right down to the typo in `dz=yz[j]-z[i]
`.

Comment: It's a typo?  I thought it was referring to another list named `yz` (I even listed that among the lists that needed to be predefined in the text right after the code!).  Surely the OP wouldn't be copying and pasting **broken** code that wouldn't even _compile_, would they?!

Comment: Okay, what do you think of this line of code: `az += f*dx`. The code he took it from (http://www.browndeertechnology.com/docs/BDT_OpenCL_Tutorial_NBody.html) seems dubious to me.

Comment: @hughdbrown, yep, really weird (though at least that wouldn't break at compile time as the other line would if `yz` was not an existing array, so it's conceivable as a "silent bug") -- still, you've convinced me to fix the probable errors in the code, just in case (tx).

Comment: @Alex: If you're going to do that, you may as well go back to the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) and implement it properly. This code is buggy enough that I don't think it does the domain problem properly. Mind you, the OP seems to be oblivious to this.

Answer (score 7):

Treat this as an ideal opportunity to learn some C, the syntax is not *so* unlike Python.

It will serve you well

Comment: +1, about the only thing in there that might trip him up is the for loop syntax (http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx). And they're basically the C equivalent to `for i in range(n)`. The rest is might even pass as valid python unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, except for the loops this *is* already very close to python ..

```
 for(j=0; j < n; ++j)
```

simply maintains the loop counter j, which is incremented after each loop iteration. The loop runs for all

```
0 <= j < n
```

. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally this code is ***extremely*** buggy, assuming the intent is to numerically integrate the n-body problem.

- The loop to calculate the force doesn't correctly handle the case i == j, resulting in a very large (depending on the size of eps) spurious error being added to each force.
- Speaking of eps, for well-posed problems it serves no purpose except to add error to your force calculation.
- The update rules for position and velocity are a strange mix of Velocity Verlet and Forward Euler, and the resulting integrator likely has all of the bad properties of the latter, at best. Velocity Verlet, being second-order, explicit, and symplectic, will give much better results for negligible cost and should be used here instead.

Comment: Re: gravity is proportional to `1/d**2` not `1/d**3`. From the wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem): "The forces are assumed here to be gravitational and given by Newton's law of universal gravitation; thus, they are proportional to the masses involved, and vary as the inverse square of the distance between the masses. The power of three in the denominator is correct, since it balances the vector difference in the numerator, which is necessary to specify the direction of the force." I am not a physics guy, but this explanation appears to be on point.